# Automatically hash primary key and make it persistent upon flush/commit with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get a hash of an objects primary key within sqlalchemy.

An example `class User` would look like this:

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ == 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hash = Column(String(38), unique=True)
```

and to add a user:

```
user = User()
session.add(user)
session.commit()

print user.id
```

I tried to hook the hashing process into ORM events, since the primary key is assigned after a `session.flush()`.
but while within the flush, changes to an objects state are not made persistent.

The only solution working for me is lazy loading the `user.id` after the first flush and than hash, assign and flush again, finally commit.

```
class User(base):
...

    @hybrid_property
    def hash(self):
        if not self.hash:
            self.hash = hash_function(self.id)
        return self.hash
```

which enables me to do the following:

```
user = User()
session.add(user)
hash = user.hash
session.commit()
```

sqlalchemy initiates an `UPDATE` and the `user.hash` and is made persistent.

But this seems like a bad option, e.g. if someone forgets to assign the hash (maybe the hash is not needed in the moment of the object creation).

Is there another option?
I'd really prefer it to be hashed automatically `after_insert`.
Maybe i'm missing something in the ORM events docs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is a good place for after_insert(), since that's the first time that the newly generated PK is consistently available (it also doesn't need to be SELECTed, but not sure what you meant by "lazy load the user.id", it should be assigned) and what you'd be looking to do is emit an UPDATE statement directly.  That's why the mapper level flush events are given the Connection (and not the Session).

Should be as easy as this:

```
@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert")
def update_hash(mapper, connection, target):
    user_table = mapper.local_table
    connection.execute(
          user_table.update().
              values(hash=hash_function(target.id)).
              where(user_table.c.id==target.id)
    )
```

if you want to make this more efficient for many users, you can do it in an after_flush() event:

```
@event.listens_for(Session, "after_flush")
def update_hash(session, flush_context):
    hashes = [
        {"user_id":element.id, "hash":hash_function(element.id)}
        for element in session.new if isinstance(element, User)
    ]
    user_table = mapper.local_table
    session.execute(
          user_table.update().
              values(hash=bind('hash')).
              where(user_table.c.id==bind('user_id')),
          hashes
    )
```

Comment: is there an elegant way to propagate those changes back to newly created object? @zzzeek

Comment: you can set the value without triggering history if you use set_committed_value(object, "hash", myhash): http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html?highlight=set_committed_value#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.set_committed_value

Comment: Is there any other method on using default `Context-Sensitive Default Functions` from http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#column-insert-update-defaults to generate the hashid directly? or Just only using the `event.listens_for` to do the job. I could hardly find any solution on this way.

Comment: Is there a way to hash before inserting? It seems to me that inserting and then updating is not a great approach, since it's two operations with one objective